# Any idea why controller is never fire?

Tags: angularjs

I use angularjs 1.2 in my project.

Here is module and controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('dashboard', ['ngRoute', 'layersProperty'])
    .controller('dashboardController', 
            function ($scope) {
                //never fire!
                var self = this;
                $scope.data = "bbbbb";
            })
})();
```

here is view:

```
<div ng-app="dashboard" data-role="page" id="layersProperty" data-add-back-btn="true" style="background-color:red">
    <div ng-controller="dashboardController">
            {{data}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that controller is never fire!Any idea why controller is never fire?

Comment: Did you include the scripts on your html page? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: @devqon, yes I included scripts and I dont get any errors in console

Comment: If you include anywhere `{{ 1+1 }}` do you get a '2' as output?

Comment: I dont get 2 I see {{ 1+1 }}

Comment: Then you either did not include the scripts or you have console errors

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you inject `ngRoute` and `layersProperty` then you have both of this JavaScript files included before your controller file where you have `dashboardController` controller. This is because, Angular will throw you `[$injector:modulerr]` error if you haven't included those code before your controller file for `dashboardController` as `dashboardController` is dependent on `ngRoute` and `layersProperty`.

In your above code if you remove `['ngRoute', 'layersProperty']` and replace it with `[]` then your conrtroller will invoke. So there must be some problem where angular could not find `ngRoute` and `layersProperty` service files.

Comment: thaks for post.This row angular.module('dashboard', ['ngRoute', 'layersProperty']) I chenge to this angular.module('dashboard', [])And still controller is not fired.I dont get any errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have reference to angularjs in your main html.